# Filtering semi duplicated rows in r dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to apply a function using a map on nested data frames. I have a function that omits out semi-duplicated lines which works well with the dataframe when it's not nested. What am I missing?
I am nesting the data , and want to keep only the o rows in each nested df, for each sno.

```
    library(tidyverse)

df<- structure(list(sno = c(4, 8, 0, 6, 4, 7, 8, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 8, 
 7, 5, 5, 9, 6, 4, 8, 3, 6, 2, 2, 5, 9, 2, 9, 4, 5, 4, 6, 1, 5, 
 0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4, 3, 7, 5, 6, 9, 1, 0, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 2, 9, 7, 
 9, 6, 8, 8, 5, 5, 4, 8, 9, 9, 9, 3, 3, 1, 9, 1, 4, 5, 4, 6, 1, 
 0, 4, 5, 6, 9, 1, 7, 9, 1, 9, 5, 2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 4, 2, 4, 9, 8, 
 4, 6, 5, 8, 7, 9, 6), source = c("o", "o", "o", "noaa", "noaa", 
 "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", 
 "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", 
 "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "o", "o", "o", "noaa", 
 "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "o", "o", "o", 
 "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", 
 "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "o", "o", "o", 
 "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "o", 
 "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "noaa", "noaa", 
 "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", 
 "o", "o", "o", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", "noaa", 
 "noaa", "o", "o", "o", "o"), Interday = c(0.031572617, 1.006481421, 
 0.398797075, 0.014500671, 0.053780664, 7.41759497, 3.627671417, 
 8.180619729, 9.189635261, 7.783972813, 5.368921544, 3.136946311, 
 8.106037688, 8.062958181, 4.103951541, 8.470729885, 7.427584491, 
 0.602268781, 0.614545781, 9.635379315, 3.056345993, 1.247191308, 
 3.497451933, 7.303090994, 1.43185095, 4.996883524, 5.48817015, 
 1.253810381, 4.508524511, 2.367587963, 1.725872942, 2.339413817, 
 0.183685533, 9.055758034, 8.806072701, 8.953997277, 8.690868045, 
 6.475162977, 2.646287983, 7.778635997, 5.803779965, 1.401676896, 
 3.611445197, 9.452437049, 0.124339579, 8.967966703, 8.053338032, 
 4.620409767, 8.082750063, 4.783511474, 6.545073505, 3.447529614, 
 4.409887626, 5.13769425, 4.683917953, 4.166658935, 3.257849192, 
 6.799425107, 0.961408628, 2.373224459, 6.728994181, 5.972543504, 
 3.285014773, 3.14187409, 3.355418447, 0.422597685, 2.746058458, 
 4.160611346, 7.015303818, 9.68060076, 3.68460242, 5.04243176, 
 4.758018753, 3.386212336, 4.69580483, 8.541438585, 4.544794886, 
 1.744579364, 5.712531666, 8.754946629, 8.108840996, 4.76947907, 
 4.984839825, 0.308128521, 4.146723167, 1.872646145, 5.583368568, 
 7.262671773, 8.782396294, 3.432045942, 3.32587702, 5.259114479, 
 9.647417579, 7.125880341, 4.940857504, 6.050258693, 6.843618824, 
 5.855545372, 8.201884823, 1.261692238, 0.667242861, 0.991640014, 
 6.341862483, 2.785033364), Area = c("N", "S", "S", "N", "S", 
 "N", "N", "N", "N", "S", "N", "S", "S", "N", "S", "N", "N", "N", 
 "N", "S", "N", "S", "S", "N", "S", "N", "N", "N", "N", "S", "N", 
 "S", "S", "N", "S", "N", "N", "N", "N", "S", "N", "S", "S", "N", 
 "S", "N", "N", "N", "N", "S", "N", "S", "S", "N", "S", "N", "N", 
 "N", "N", "S", "N", "S", "S", "N", "S", "N", "N", "N", "N", "S", 
 "N", "S", "S", "N", "S", "N", "N", "N", "N", "S", "N", "S", "S", 
 "N", "S", "N", "N", "N", "N", "S", "N", "S", "S", "N", "S", "N", 
 "N", "N", "N", "S", "N", "S", "S", "N"), Color = c("red", "red", 
 "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", 
 "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "blue", "red", "red", "red", 
 "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "blue", 
 "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", 
 "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "red", "red", "red", 
 "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
 "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
 "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
 "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", 
 "red", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", 
 "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "blue", 
 "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "red", 
 "red")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
 ), row.names = c(NA, -104L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
 sno = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
 )), source = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
 "collector")), Interday = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
 "collector")), Area = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
 "collector")), Color = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
 "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
 "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))


 df_nested<- df %>% group_by(Area, Color) %>% nest()
```

Another example, maybe better explained. Let's say I nested some weather data.
No for each day inside the nested data, I want to keep only records that timedate matches a specific formula. For the example below keep only the record of time_hour == "2013-01-01 14:00:00" for example.

```
fl <- nycflights13::weather
fl<- fl %>% group_by(origin) %>% nest()
```

Comment: Significant edits were made. I hope it helps to clear the question

Answer (score 0):

On the `nest`ed dataset, update the 'data' column with `mutate` by filtering the rows with `slice` on each of the `list` elements of 'data'.  Here, `match` returns an integer index position of the first match which is fed to `slice` to return only that row for that `list` 'data'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df_nested_slice <- df %>%
     group_by(sno) %>% 
     nest %>% 
     mutate(data = map(data,  ~ .x %>% 
                       slice(match("o", source, nomatch = 1))))
```

We could `unnest` if needed

```
out2 <- df_nested_slice %>%
      unnest(c(data)) %>%
      arrange(sno)
```

and check with the output of the `slice`ed cases where there is no `nest`ing

---

The OP's first case also can be done with `slice`

```
out1 <- df %>% 
   group_by(sno) %>% 
   slice(match("o", source, nomatch = 1)) %>%
   arrange(sno)
```

-checking the outputs

```
all.equal(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @Stat.Enthus Not clear.  The solutions are based on your input example

Comment: Thanks. Iv'e edited my original post. Hope it's better